# SQLAlchemy: create sqlalchemy query from sql query with subquery and inner join

Tags: python, oracle, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to backend development and python. I'm working on creating a SQLAlchemy query from SQL query which has subquery and inner join.

I'm using python > 3.5, "oracle+cx_oracle" driver and SQLAlchemy==1.3.6

The SQL query that I need to convert is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*, t.max_date, t.USER_ID
FROM DATABASE_ONE d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT USER_ID, MAX(DATE_CREATED) max_date FROM (
        SELECT * FROM DATABASE_ONE
        WHERE USER_ID IN ('1','2','3')
        AND CATEGORY = 'Users'
        AND IS_DELETED IS NULL
    )
    GROUP  BY USER_ID
) t on t.USER_ID = d.USER_ID AND t.max_date = d.DATE_CREATED
```

Below is the code that I've tried to convert the above SQL query to SQLAlchemy query.

```
    # --------------------- first query -------------------

    first_query = (
        Session.query(DatabaseOne)
        .filter(
            DatabaseOne.user_id.in_('1', '2', '3'),
            DatabaseOne.category == "Obligor Rating Scorecards",
            DatabaseOne.is_deleted == None,
        )
        .subquery("first_query")
    )

    # -------------------- second query --------------------

    second_query = (
        Session.query(
            DatabaseOne.user_id,
            func.max(DatabaseOne.date_created).label("max_date"),
        )
        .select_from(first_query)
        .group_by(DatabaseOne.user_id)
        .subquery("second_query")
    )

    # -------------------- final query --------------------

    final_query = (
        Session.query(
            DatabaseOne, second_query.c.max_date, second_query.c.user_id
        )
        .join(
            second_query,
            and_(
                second_query.c.user_id == DatabaseOne.user_id,
                DatabaseOne.date_created == second_query.c.max_date,
            ),
        )
        .distinct(DatabaseOne)
        .all()
    )
```

- I was able to get expected results on **first_query**.
- **second_query** failed to give the expected results.
- I'm not sure if **final_query** is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your SQL I think you are trying to query the lines which user_id is given and with max date.
So first maybe we can update the SQL a little:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*, t.max_date, t.USER_ID
FROM DATABASE_ONE d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT USER_ID, MAX(DATE_CREATED) max_date 
    FROM DATABASE_ONE
    WHERE 
        USER_ID IN ('1','2','3')
        AND CATEGORY = 'Users'
        AND IS_DELETED IS NULL
    GROUP  BY USER_ID
) t on t.USER_ID = d.USER_ID AND t.max_date = d.DATE_CREATED
```

In these case it's easier to read and convert into SQLAlchemy language.

---

Then the problem about your second SQLAlchemy query, is that you are trying to select from a subquery but the select is from origin table. If convert the second SQLAlchemy query into sql query, It's will look like:

```
SELECT DATABASE_ONE.USER_ID, MAX(DATABASE_ONE.DATE_CREATED) max_date FROM (
    SELECT * FROM DATABASE_ONE
    WHERE USER_ID IN ('1','2','3')
    AND CATEGORY = 'Users'
    AND IS_DELETED IS NULL
)
GROUP  BY DATABASE_ONE.USER_ID
```

The better way to write the SQLAlchemy query:

```
    subquery = Session.query(
        DatabaseOne.user_id,
        func.max(DatabaseOne.date_created).label("max_date"),
    )
    .filter(
        DatabaseOne.user_id.in_('1', '2', '3'),
        DatabaseOne.category == "Obligor Rating Scorecards",
        DatabaseOne.is_deleted == None,
    )
    .group_by(DatabaseOne.user_id)
    .subquery()

    Session.query(
        DatabaseOne, subquery.c.user_id, subquery.c.max_date # see the .c method to access column in subquery
    ).select_from(subquery).join(DatabaseOne).filter(DatabaseOne.user_id = subquery.c.user_id,DatabaseOne.date_created = subquery.c.max_date).all()
```